# The meaning of "back from the edge"?

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrase-usage

As a non-English speaker, I always find it's hard to understand the implications of the columnist Charles Krauthammer in his articles as much as I feel admired to his knowledge and word skills. This time, after reading an [article](http://www.weeklystandard.com/the-mayor-the-museum-and-the-madonna/article/11946) about 'art', at his conclusion, I saw Krauthammer used the phrase "**back from the edge**" in the following context:

> *"Ah, but every once in a while a burgher arises and says to the artist: **No need to report back from the edge**. You can stay where you are. We’ll have our afternoon tea **without acid**, thank you."*

that I couldn't figure out what did he want to say in that sentence. Besides, I also couldn't get the idea of **"tea without acid"** in the last one.

So, could someone kindly help me a hand in this situation? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

"Back from the edge" would generally mean moving back from some risky situation - but in this case the phrase isn't really used that way... instead the key is "the edge". The implication is that artists live on the edge and do "edgy" things like taking acid (LSD) - whereas sober burghers have boring  cups of tea.

Answer (score 1):

The reasons you're a little confused would be because you're leaving out the word *report*.  The complete phrase in question would then be, *report back from the edge*.  Without reading the article I would assume the *edge* is short for 'cutting edge' being, "the most modern stage of development in a particular type of work or activity".

It could also refer to teetering on the edge of something. The edge of stardom, for instance, means almost famous, but not quite there yet.

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/cutting-edge

There is a lot of sarcasm in the paragraph in question, and 'tea without acid' might refer to the 'sting' of an action.  To preface that, someone with an *acid tongue* makes nasty or hurtful remarks without considering the consequences.

*We’ll have our afternoon tea without acid*, means, "We don't need your input/opinion/advice", etc.